# How to use gitignore on c9.io for adding .c9revisions/ folder

Tags: git, github, cloud, gitignore, cloud9-ide

How can i edit gitignore on Cloud9 (c9.io) so i can add the .c9revisions/ folder to it to avoid adding it to my repo on github.

Everytime i use git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global it just does not do anything, can anyone help me out with that, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That [Google+ tips](https://plus.google.com/101256894969172700518/posts/HqcXd425yJM) mentions:

> tip: edit your `.gitignore` file even though it doesn't show in the "`project files`":
>
> At the command line, simply enter:

```
open .gitignore
```

> and see the file display and edit in a new tab.
> Save, commit, etc.

From [this issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/pull/1298), it looks like Cloud9 is still not ignoring automatically the `.c9revisions` folder (and the `settings.xml`, and everything else related to C9).

---

The [OP Sergio Robledo Arango](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887292/sergio-robledo-arango) mentions he had to create that file:

[image: https://skitch-img.s3.amazonaws.com/20121001-k6fj6ng8hmrpbj5hn7kcyy6fh2.png]

Comment: Thank you, that works too but the problem i had also was that .gitignore file was not even in my workspace so all i had to do is create one and edit it, look at the following [image](https://skitch.com/detmarterhuurne/esgph/business-rules-cloud9)

Comment: @SergioRobledoArango Ok, I have added the picture in the answer, for more visibility.